# Android - Update GridView on button click

Tags: android, gridview, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to set up a gridview that will refresh when a new search is executed.

this is my call to set up the gridview

```
    final GridElement_Results adapter = new GridElement_Results(this, savedInstanceState, track_name, album_name, track_num, album_id, album_link);
    grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid_results);
    grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As you can see, I am passing it a bunch of arrays.

On a button click, the function getTracks() is called which gets new data from the server. The arrays are updated with the new data, which I have verified is working.

```
icon_activesearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {

                                        getTracks("newsearchterm");

                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        grid.invalidateViews();

                                    }
                                }
    );
```

And then I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and grid.invalidateViews() to update and redraw the grid. But obviously I'm doing something wrong here.

Is it because I'm setting the adapter as final? To access it within the onClick method I need to set it to final.

What should I change to get it to work.

Comment: add `getTracks()` method

Comment: Are you passing the new results to your adapter?

Comment: from what I see you are not passing an object of type List, ArrayList or Array to your adapter. How exactly does the adapter get the data that it shows ?

Comment: I should've added: getTracks() updates a set of global arrays: track_name, album_name etc. I thought that once these arrays are updated, and notifyDataSetChanged() is called, the grid would update automatically.

How would I pass these arrays to the existing adapter again, without creating a new adapter?

Answer (score 0):

you should wait until new data fetch then notify adapter but you call notify just after getTracks() without any delay

Comment: Do you mean that notifyDataSetChanged is being called before the http request is completed? How can I add a delay? Sleep?